# jQuery alias for script specific

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wordpress ships jQuery in safe mode, this is very awesome, but a 3rd party script that I must use uses the `$` alias, so there's a way of alias `$` to `jQuery` only for that script ? (can't edit the script since it's 3rd party)

Comment: A 3rd party script that doesn't consider the possibility of overriding `$` (and fail when it is) is not a good script...

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon I agree, but the worst part is: unfortunately it's from Payza integration API

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>wrap the initialisation of the plugin in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)</strike>

```
(function($){
   $('.some').pluginUsingDollarAsJQuery();
})(jQuery)
```

---

As per the [help pages for plugin authorship](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope):

> The $ variable is very popular among JavaScript libraries, and if you're using another library with jQuery, you will have to make jQuery not use the $ with jQuery.noConflict(). However, this will break our plugin since it is written with the assumption that $ is an alias to the jQuery function. To work well with other plugins, and still use the jQuery $ alias, we need to put all of our code inside of an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, and then pass the function jQuery, and name the parameter

Which basically boils down to the fact that whoever has written the plugin you're using has not done it right.

Writing a plugin like this:

```
$.fn.doSomething = function(){
   // whatever
}
```

Will make it not compatible with anyone using jQuery in noConflict mode. It should be wrapped in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) like this:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.doSomething = function(){
       // whatever
    }
})(jQuery)
```

If your plugin is the former style, ditch it.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't work like that. I think a lot of people misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - I didnt misunderstand the question - I thought something would work that doesnt. Anyway, answer updated.

Comment: "If your plugin is the former style, ditch it." it's... a very good advice, up votted but I can't accept as answer since it doesn't actually solves.

Comment: @VictorAurélio - can you not just open the plugin and wrap it in the IIFE?

Comment: @Jamiec as temporary solution I did this, but I've contacted the developer to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

[Jamiec's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31343089/2324107) is the clean solution which should be used if you have access to the code, but in case you do not have access to it, there is a dirty solution.

You can reassign `$` to jQuery just before the script is loaded. So when the script is initializing, `$ === jQuery`.

To do it when the script is inline in the DOM, just open a script tag for the reassignment before :

```
<script>$=jQuery;</script>
<script src="external_script"></script>
```

If you load dynamically the script (ex : `jQuery.getScript`), you can reassign just before calling the async function :

```
window.$ = jQuery;
jQuery.getScript('external_source');
```

**WARNING :** this method can break your script if `window.$` was used elsewhere. It may also not work if the script is loaded asynchronous if, meanwhile, another script reassign `$` to something else.