# Wordpress accordion menu dont work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I have the following page https://german-academic-institute.eu/faqs/ with the WPBakery plugin that has the Accordion menu for FAQs in the middle of the page. All those menus are made to be closed, but for some reason, they are not, and the option to close/open them doesn't work when I click on them. I tested also other collapsable menus and the same thing happens. SO I assume it has to do something with Jquery but can't figure it out.

I could use any help

Thanks.

Comment: The order of synchronous scripts in head matters. Your script `jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker()` is referencing jQuery before it has loaded by the browser. BTW, You are loading jQuery more than one time, mostly it is enough to load a library just once.

Comment: Moreover, the `$` can be an alias for jQuery. Please, read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31343034/jquery-alias-for-script-specific) and the accepted answer. Also this will help You: [Protecting the $ Alias and Adding Scope](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope). I strongly believe You don't need the `$` alias.

Comment: Please specify you error on lines with description and code. 

i was commented if you need update jquery.
remember update you question, and describe you problem here!

Answer (score 2):

Dev Tools and browser Console is your friend. You can reach it by right-clicking on the page and from the menu shown chosing Inspect/Inspect Element (the actual text varies accross browsers). In the Dev Tools if you click on the Console tab, you will see the errors in the browser and can experiment with scripts. Kindly look at this image:

[image]

You have rightly guessed that the problem is with `jQuery`, as your page attempts to reach jQuery with that variable name, however, in your case jQuery is called `$`.

A quick fix is to create the variable before it is being attempted to be used:

```
var jQuery = $;
```

or replacing `jQuery` with `$` in all its occurrence. Kindly note the thought process of the solution:

- I looked at the error and figured out that the variable is missing
- I checked whether the variable is called `$` instead of `jQuery`
- Based on the acquired knowledge I have made a plan and written an answer to you

Comment: thanks for your reply. I did check as instructed trough CHrome Dev Tools and only error I see is for this part of code:

  jQuery( function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );

but nothing else shows as error. I did added your var jQeurry =$; inside header part but still accorion menues are not opening or closing as before. Where exactly I need to add your part of code? Thanks.

Comment: @BorisZegarac you have a typo in the code you have shown in the comment. You need to make sure that `var jQuery = $;` is executed before the code that is crashing, notably the datepicker-related code. If you add this line and the issue still persists, then the line you added was not executed before it was attempted to be used. Can you detect where the jQuery-related code that's crashing is?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed datepicker part of code and even disabled that plugin, and nothing, still accordion was not working after that. Not sure if something else is blocking it.

Comment: @BorisZegarac according to my findings when I visited your page, the site was trying to use jQuery instead of $. So you clearly have some script that tries to use jQuery by an incorrect name. I would search for the word **jQuery** in the whole project if I were you to see where it is being used. Among the findings you might encounter the problem. Also, if there were large changes on your page, please do let me know here in the comment section, I would visit the page again.

Answer (score 1):

The `datepicker` appears to be blocking the accordion functionality from being available.

[This is the `datepicker` "script" in the `<head>` of the page markup. Searching the page, this is the only instance of `datepicker` in the markup and as the console shows, blocks other code - such as the accordion - from running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFAOp.png)

[Console showing the error. Since the `datepicker` is basically at the top of the page, it will prevent JavaScript that is below it from executing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bofR6.png)

I was unable to even find anything related to the accordion functionality (in terms of the actual script that would have the accordion functionality in it), but after a bit of time in the console, I came up with this ugly jQuery - `jQuery(".vc_tta-panel-heading a").click(function(e){e.preventDefault; jQuery(e.target).parents('.vc_tta-panel').children('.vc_tta-panel-body').toggle()})`. Which is what the plugin should do. Not exactly an answer, but you might have better luck contacting the plugin author for advisement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I removed datepicker part of code and even disabled that plugin, and nothing, still accordion was not working after that. Not sure if something else is blocking it.

Answer (score 1):

Go ahead.

```
<!-- <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>  --> 
you can update!

<script type="text/javacript">
//replace

  jQuery( function() {
    jQuery( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });

   $(document).ready(function(){
       //include you datepicker function.

   })
  </script>
<!-- Nice once -->

 > note : is good practice include in section 

  > styles
  > html sections
  > tags lines javascript and includes
```